# VESA vertical offset mount bracket

Tags: gaming, monitors, multiple-monitors

I have a need for something that I can only describe as a "drop mount" or a vertical offset bracket for 100x100mm VESA mount holes.

I have a 3-monitor setup with an iMac as the middle screen, using [this](https://www.echogear.com/gaming-monitor-mounts/adjustable-triple-monitor-desk-mount/) monitor mount.  The problem with the iMac is that they have a very large "chin", and the VESA mount kit that Apple sells is centered to the body, not the screen.  The result is that the two screens mounted to the sides are about an inch lower than the screen in the center.

What I need is a bracket for the iMac with two sets of 100x100mm holes that are offset an inch from each other, so I can mount the center screen lower than the other two.

The closest thing I've found is [this height-adjustable bracket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0741CFJVW) which would do the trick, but the problem is that it only supports up to 17.6 lbs of weight (the iMac weighs 20).

It shouldn't be this hard to find a simple metal plate with holes in it, but I'm having a hard time even figuring out what to call it, let alone finding one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about adjusting the monitors on each side with that bracket?